# Tensorflow reset Adam Optimizer internal state every n minibatches

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, gradient

That is my question:
How to reset the Tensorflow Adam Optimizer internal state every n mini batches?

By internal state I mean the m(t), past gradients, and v(t), past squared gradients, parameters.

Answer (score 3):

I would do it like this:

- Give the Adam Optimizer a distinct name
- Get all the variables associated with this name
- Re-Initialize all those variables.

Or written in code ( you will probably want a better name than 'Adam'):

```
 optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001, name='Adam').minimize(loss)
 adam_vars = [var for var in tf.all_variables() if 'Adam' in var.name]
 sess.run(tf.variables_initializer(adam_vars))
```

Edit (25.04.2019):

There is an easier way to do this:

```
 optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
 train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
 sess.run(tf.variables_initializer(optimizer.variables()))
```